Swipe down to dismiss with embedded List
My SwiftUI view is presented modally, and swipe down to dismiss only work on the 'static' part of the view, but not on the List, because it's embedded and won't forward the swipe down gesture to the modal's presentation environment.
VStack {
    HStack {
        // Some static content
    }
    TabView {
        List { // PROBLEM: swipe down on the list when its scroll is at the top won't dismiss the modal
        }
    }
}

How can I achieve that?
Putting everything in a List (top view) works, but this is a no-go solution as it has too many side-effects.
